# How to scroll/slide down google map background into the view with page scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

I have a **Google Map** as my background. Currently it is exactly where I want it when I load the page, but when I scroll down it goes out of view. How can I scroll the google map down so that it is always in the background?

My css:

```
#map-canvas {
  top:0;
  height: 100vh;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-10000;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%
}
```

I have also tried `position:fixed` and tried the following dom structure with `position:fixed` on `#mapCanvScroller`, but it doesn't work:

```
<div id="mapCanvScroller">
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you put it in a jsfidde?

Answer (score 0):

create a div whose height and width is 100% of the body tag and apply the background image to this div make overflow has hidden for this div. After that create a child div inside that div which will be scrollable. Scrolling will cause the content of the inner div to scroll not outer div and your background image will remain same

Comment: try with position as fixed

Answer (score 0):

You should add scrollwheel: false in your option

```
var myOptions = {
    scrollwheel: false,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.759118, -73.985110),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
```

Is that you want?
DEMO:http://jsfiddle.net/2crQ7/275/